# How do I get the wifi on my computer to work?

Tags: drivers, iwlwifi, 21.10, wifi-hardware-switch

The wifi on my MSI PS42 laptop stopped working after an Ubuntu Base update. Only ethernet functions at present. Problem has not fixed itself after updating from 21.04 to 21.10.

Looked into **additional drivers** in **software & updates** to check for drivers, none are available.

**Network card model is Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi**

**sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl**

```
[    2.691703] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.709264] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 0
[    2.709270] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[    2.709272] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[    2.709274] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[    2.709276] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[    2.709277] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[    2.709279] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[    2.709281] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[    2.709282] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[    2.709284] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[    2.709286] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[    2.709287] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[    2.709289] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[    2.709291] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[    2.709292] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 20
[    2.709294] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 21
[    2.709295] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 28
[    2.709915] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6b541b68.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.776598] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x318
[    3.796049] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x2318
[    3.796058] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    4.044829] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    4.044866] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[    4.044867] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM error/state
[    4.044885] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM data1
[    4.044896] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    4.044904] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8D824954 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    4.044912] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    4.044921] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x667B8C02 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    4.044929] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    4.044937] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8D079AAF | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    4.044946] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCFE8A255 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    4.044954] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x77347C69 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    4.044962] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6417ECA2 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    4.044971] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.044981] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.044992] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    4.045033] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    4.045042] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    4.045053] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    4.778185] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

**rfkill list all**
rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

**~# sudo dmesg | grep INIT**

```
[    2.037143] systemd[1]: systemd 248.3-1ubuntu8 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS -OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS -FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP -LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY -P11KIT -QRENCODE +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified)
[    4.172091] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    4.172100] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x767B8C02 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    4.172227] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    4.935720] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please add to your question output of the command `ip a`

Answer (score 0):

This will be a provisional answer as further investigation continues.

First, if this is a dual-boot with Windows, please disable Fast Boot: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Next, let's try a driver parameter:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi uapsd_disable=1"  >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Reboot and check:

```
sudo dmesg | grep INIT
```

Reference: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1918191#p1918191 (NOTE: Although there are several possible driver parameters discussed here, I'd prefer to try only the most likely one at a time.)

Finally, `soft blocked:yes` usually indicates that wireless networking is not enabled in Network Manager. Please use Settings to enable it.

Comment: "soft blocked:yes usually indicates that wireless networking is not enabled"                        
This is one of the problems, wireless is not visible in network settings, only wired comes up.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for resurrecting an old thread, just wanted to share a possible solution.  I had a similar problem with getting Intel WiFi 6E AX211 to work with Ubuntu 20.04.  What solved it for me was to install an additional kernel module for iwlwifi.  I came across it while searching the kernel packages available for focal (20.04).
https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kernel/

If you're using a different version of Ubuntu, just replace focal in the URL above with your version.  i.e., jammy for 22.04, lunar for 23.04, etc.

Specifically for my case, I installed linux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-91-generic , rebooted, and now my wifi works.